# Adding panels with fixed 2 rows and multiple columns dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, alignment

I want to add a panel dynamically with this structure. It should grow in a column and also if I delete panel in middle next panels should move before.

```
Panel1      panel3      panel5 ....

Panel2      panel4      panel6 ....
```

I tried the column layout but its growing in columnwise. I tried to update the layout with
`vertical: true`.

```js
if (itemLength % 2 === 1 && itemLength !== 0) {
    container.setLayout({
        vertical : true
    })
} else {
    container.setLayout({
        vertical : false
    })
}
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hbox` layout for container in which you want to add panels horizontally and `vbox` for vertically.

```
{
   xtype: 'panel',
   layout: {
       type: 'hbox',
       align: 'stretch'
   }
},
```

And provide flex to adjust height and width accordingly while adding or deleting.

```
flex: 1;
```

[Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32a5) You can find the working fiddle for your scenario. When you click on add button, a panel will be added to your container horizontally having a delete button and width will be adjusted accordingly and same will be taken care on deletion.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is working fine. But I want to place panel2  down  the panel1 and panel3 to the right  of panel1 dynamically. Exactly to say, it should work opposite to column layout. It should have only two rows and grow rowwise instead of columnwise.

Comment: thats what i said, For vertical alignments you have to use vbox layout. so you can write the logic as per your need.